# Can yaml key values be pulled from Redis Cache in a Spring Boot Application?

Tags: spring-boot, redis, yaml

YAML Example:

`demo:
  environment: prod
  hosts:
    - https://www.example1.com
    - https://www.example2.com`

Is it possible to pull values from Redis Cache and into the YAML?  Or do all YAML key/values need to be entered before hand?

i.e. 
`environment: {env.name}`